# Вывод элементов массива в зависимости от их длины

Tags: c#, консоль

Добрый день.

Есть стринговый массив `string[] mas = { "a", "aa", "b", "ab", "abc", "a", "abcde" };`

Нужно вывести все элементы, где длина больше трех символов.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это делается через лямбда или линк.

Спасибо.

Comment: А обычный цикл с условием не подходит? Думаю, что он Вам и нужен.

Comment: Как обычным циклом, я знаю, мне интересно, как это сделать с помощью линка и лямбды))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, например:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", mas.Where(x => x.Length > 3)));
```

[Проверка](http://ideone.com/5jsNhs).